# Transform same columns headers into different set of rows (transform columns in rows)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-wrangling

all good?

I'm trying to transform columns into rows using Power Query for the following example table:

(actual table)

[image]

I need to resume columns A,B (and more) into a single column called ID, for example:

(Expected table)

[image]

I have tried to use the feature "Transform Columns into Rows", but I'm stuck with the following result:

[image]

The solution seems to be very simple but I can't help myself resolving it, could you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in M / Powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Names2=List.Alternate(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1,1,1),
Names1={Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}} & List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Names2),
Part1 = Table.SelectColumns(Source,Names1),
#"Rename1" = Table.RenameColumns( Part1, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Part1 ), List.Transform({1 .. List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Part1))}, each "Column"&Text.From(_)) } ) ),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Rename1", "ID", each Table.ColumnNames(Part1){1}),
Part2 = Table.SelectColumns(Source,Names2),
#"Rename2" = Table.RenameColumns( Part2, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Part2 ), List.Transform({1 .. List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Part2))}, each "Column"&Text.From(_)) } ) ),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Rename2", "ID", each Table.ColumnNames(Part2){1}),
combined=#"Added Custom"&#"Added Custom2"
in combined
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
leading=1, groupsof=2,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),leading+groupsof)),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"FatherID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"FatherID", "Attribute"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Value", "Index"}, {"Value", "Index"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Value", type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}}, "Attribute", "Value"),
removesuffix = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute",each Text.Remove(_,{"0".."9"}), type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(removesuffix, {Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}, "Attribute"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Value", "Index"}, {"Value", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for the codes. Could you explain one of them? I'm struggling to translate them into my code here.

Comment: Not a problem anymore, I got it here. Thank you for your help! I was struggling to understand the code itself and rules, but now its fine.